# TypeError: animation._isUsingNativeDriver is not a function. (In 'animation._isUsingNativeDriver()', 'animation._isUsingNativeDriver' is undefined)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In my react-native app I want to have a circle pulse animation loop, I'm still a noob using Animated API, I'm getting the error in title.

My code.

```
const animatedValue = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;  

    const onPressIn = ()=>{
        Animated.loop([
          Animated.timing(animatedValue, {
            toValue: 2.2,
            duration: 2000,
            useNativeDriver:true,
          }),
          Animated.timing(animatedValue, {
            toValue: 0.9,
            duration: 700,
            useNativeDriver:true,
          })
        ],{useNativeDriver:true}).start()
    };

<Animated.View style={{width:70,height:70,borderRadius:70/2,backgroundColor:'red',transform:[{scale:animatedValue}], position:'absolute',top:10,right:10,zIndex:9999999999}} >
            
        </Animated.View>
```

When I remove useNativeDriver from my function error disappears...